# How do I stop the Minecraft launcher from warning me about using modified Minecraft installs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-launcher

The Minecraft launcher recently updated to add support for Microsoft accounts, it also changed the background and added a warning when I hover over modified profiles in the selection tab (*This installation has been modified and might not support the latest player safety features.*). I always use the Fabric modloader and I don't care about not having access to the "latest player safety features" and I've kinda had enough of Minecraft nagging me every time I switch versions when I want to play on different servers. I am not going to accept "Stop using mods" as an answer, as I do not intend to do so. I have searched across google for answers but haven't been able to find information regarding this anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the `.minecraft` folder in `%appdata%` and open the `launcher_profiles.json` file.

Scroll to the desired profile name (e.g. Optifine).
Then change the "type" to `"Void-Null"`. Then restart the Minecraft launcher with beta mode enabled in the settings.

Example of mine when done:

```
"OptiFine" : {
      "created" : "2020-08-27T07:48:53.976Z",
      "icon" : "Grass",
      "javaArgs" : "-Xmx10G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M",
      "lastUsed" : "2020-12-02T18:16:50.180Z",
      "lastVersionId" : "1.16.4",
      "name" : "OptiFine",
      "type" : "Void-Null"
}
```

Comment: It actually is better if it *is* formatted because it is much easier to read. Your answer can help many more people when it is formatted. I have suggested an edit to improve the formatting, but next time it is encouraged to edit it if you'd like.

Comment: Is this an official workaround? I can't find documentation of that exact profile type anywhere and it seems to have no effect for me.